# How can recover my motodev.keystore password?

Tags: android, keystore, motodev-studio

I completely forgot the password for my `motodev.keystore` file and thus cannot import this keystore file into another PC running *MotoDevStudio*. Is there any way to recover the password of the `motodev.keystore` file?

Comment: This is a question about a software tool used for developing Android apps, though. Android SE is for *end-user* questions about the Android OS. Besides, Moto Dev Studio and its keystore certainly seems like they fit within the FAQ section that explicitly includes "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: Questions about development tools and their use such as this one are perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystore-password-recovery